# Setting up Qt Creator for linking and compiling assembly code

Tags: c++, qt, assembly, nasm, qmake

I've been studying C++ and x64 Assembly the last weeks and would like to get into GUI programming with the Qt IDE. The problem is that I can't find a way to link and compile a file containing assembly code. I've been browsing the internet and this site without finding anything helpful.

Here is what I have tried so far:
.pro

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -save-temps
QT       += core gui
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
TARGET = test---
TEMPLATE = app
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += nasm

SOURCES += main.cpp\
    mainwindow.cpp\
    asm.s

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h
FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
//code
extern "C" __int64 assembly();

//code

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    int zahl = assembly(); // place what the assembly function return into "zahl"
}
```

asm.s

```
.code
.global
assembly proc

mov rax, 1
ret

xor rax, rax

assembly endp
end
```

[Build setup img](http://cosmocortney.ddns.net/test/test---.zip)

Attempting to compile the project leads to following error message:

```
mainwindow.obj:-1: Fehler: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol assembly referenced in function "private: void __cdecl MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked(void)" (?on_pushButton_clicked@MainWindow@@AEAAXXZ)
```

I have also found a setup guide on this for console applications. But it doesn't seem to be suitable for GUI applications: http ://dvisagie.blogspot.de/2011/09/setting-up-qt-creator-for-assemblylinux.html

Here's how I've been compiling assembly files in Visual Studio:
.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

extern "C" __int64 _stdcall assembly();

int main()
{
    cout << assembly() << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

.asm:
    .code
    assembly proc

```
mov rax, 1234
ret
xor rax, rax

assembly endp
end
```

EDIT: [appended build](http://cosmocortney.ddns.net/test/test---.zip)

Comment: Have a look at https://wiki.qt.io/Undocumented_QMake#Custom_tools

Comment: No success. Do you possibly know how to properly format these definitions for my project?

EDIT: QMAKE_FILE_IN — this is the input filename(s), with path 
Does this mean I have to replace QMAKE_FILE_IN with the filename + path?

Comment: See https://github.com/Skycoder42/QtRestClient/blob/master/mkspecs/features/qrestbuilder.prf#L14 as an example. `REST_API_CLASSES` would be the variable for the project file. In case you still have problems, I can create a full answer with the code for your problem, but not before tomorrow...

Comment: @Felix Still can't get it to work. Here's the download link to the project: https://mega.nz/#!31dDGTLJ!V-D2EytdyON1-56d4J7FOOCt_DJLawj4xDttxl6N1QE thank you for offering your help

Comment: On Windows, you need to decoraty external symbols with a leading underscore, so `_assembly` instead of `assembly` in your assembly file.  That explains the linking errors on Windows.

Comment: Note further that `nasm` doesn't actually use `proc` and `endp`; that's a MASM thing.  Given that your file suffix is `.s` and not `.asm`, it looks like gas is used to assemble your code, which is weird.

Answer (score 1):

The code should look like this (in your pro file). The first compiler (nasm) generates the lst file from the asm file. The second compiler (nasm_ld) then runs ld to generate an object file.

For the nasm compiler, `ASM_FILES` is the input variable that it reads from, and writes the name of the generated lst to `LST_FILES`, which is the processed by nasm_ld and the objects added to `OBJECTS`, which should make the available for the linker.

```
nasm.name = nasm ${QMAKE_FILE_IN}
nasm.input = ASM_FILES
nasm.variable_out = OBJECTS
nasm.commands = nasm -f win64 ${QMAKE_FILE_IN} -o ${QMAKE_FILE_OUT}
nasm.output = ${QMAKE_VAR_OBJECTS_DIR}${QMAKE_FILE_IN_BASE}$${first(QMAKE_EXT_OBJ)}
nasm.CONFIG += target_predeps

QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS  += nasm

ASM_FILES += asm.s
```

**Edit:** I have updated the code based on the comments. Try if this works. It should compile the asm file and add the object file to the linker. Please remove your custom build step first.

Comment: Thank you, any advice on what to adjust the compiler commands to?
I couldn't get any compilation

Comment: I never used assembler, so no clue. Try to get you build working on the command line, read some tutorials on how to use nasm. The compiler command is basically what you type on console, with filenames replaced by those variables

Comment: hmm, I'm afraid, I can't seem to find the right tutorial.
ahm.. or do I have to replace _ASM..FILES_, _LST..FILES_ and _OBJECTS_ with the actual files (since these are variables)

Comment: Not in the pro file. If you're trying it on the command line, yes (i.e. try if `nasm -f elf -g -F stabs asm.s asm.lst` works on the command line.

Comment: No luck. Is there probably anything wrong with my project settings:
[img]http://cosmocortney.ddns.net/test/pjk.png [/img]

Comment: You should have mentioned your on windows... As this link you provided was for linux, I thought you were building on linux as well!

Comment: Please update your quesion and show an example how you used to compile your assemblies before using Qt. If I can see a working example, I can update my answer

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I have updated the post showing how I've been compiling assembly files with Visual Studio

Comment: Okay, so Visual Studio does the work for you. Please try if `nasm -f win32 asm.s -o asm.o` works. If not, you may need to add nasm to your path. If it works (i.e. produces the asm.o without an error), I can update my solution from above. Taken from here: http://ccm.net/faq/1559-compiling-an-assembly-program-with-nasm#with-windows. If you encounter errors, try to follow that tutorial

Comment: The download did not provide the nasm. exe. So I got nasm from another source. Just after changing the command to `nasm -f win64 asm.s -o asm.o` provided me an x64 assembly object. `mov rax....` became `48B8` in hex LE which indeed is a mov instruction with rax. So is there a way to automate this procedure in my .pro file? If yes, then will there be a way to define function names and such like I did in VS?
Thanks!

Comment: Little Update: I have added _nasm.exe_ to the build settings and added the the comment you've provided in your last post: ` -f win64 D:\Dokumente\test---\asm.asm -o D:\Dokumente\test---\asm.o`
It now builds the .o file in the same folder! But the _proc_, _endp_ and _end_ instructions don't get recognized. Therefore I can't define a function to call up in my c++ project. The contents of the .o file are not present in the .exe

Comment: See updated answer. Remove the custom build step and try with this

Comment: thanks, still no success. Something's missing in ћ pro file?
`# += of QT TARGET TEMPLATE DEFINES
SOURCES += main.cpp\
mainwindow.cpp\
asm.s\
asm.o #w/ this it now compiles & adds ћ .o into a subfolder

HEADERS += mainwindow.h

FORMS += mainwindow.ui

nasm.name = nasm ${QMAKE_FILE_IN}

nasm.input = ASM_FILES

nasm.variable_out = OBJECTS

nasm.commands = nasm -f win64 ${QMAKE_FILE_IN} -o ${QMAKE_FILE_OUT}

nasm.output = ${QMAKE_VAR_OBJECTS_DIR}${QMAKE_FILE_IN_BASE}$${first(QMAKE_EXT_OBJ)}

nasm.CONFIG += target_predeps

QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += nasm

ASM_FILES += asm.s`

Comment: Don't add `asm.s` and `asm.o` to `SOURCES`. Delete the build folder, as this sometimes helps. If it still does not work, please append the build output to you question, as I need to see what happens to help you further.

Comment: appended it on the bottom of the post

Comment: Sorry, I meant the build log (i.e. the console output the compiler generates). In QtCreator, it's the compile tab on the bottom. Just copy all the text in there.

Comment: Oh, I see now. well, it outputs the 2 same errors as all the time before:
　　　　　mainwindow.obj:-1: Fehler: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol assembly referenced in function "private: void __cdecl MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked(void)" (?on_pushButton_clicked@MainWindow@@AEAAXXZ)

　　　　　　
debug\test---.exe:-1: Fehler: LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Comment: Not the errors, the compile log. As I see your german: Unten der Tab "4 Kompilierung", da sollte jede Menge Text stehen, den brauche ich

Comment: Sorry, my bad! you can find all the text here: http://cosmocortney.ddns.net/test/test.txt

Comment: Okay, I have to admit I have no clue what windows is doing here. Apparently, The linker does not find the object file of the assembly, but I can't tell you why. If Visual Studio does this for you, you could try to build the qt project with visual studio. See https://doc.qt.io/qtvstools/qtvstools-getting-started.html

Comment: wow, got it working. But with masm (not nasm). That'd be a problem if any commercial use of this will happen. I have noticed the syntax differs at some points. `ui->label....` became` ui.label...` and `label`is marked as an error even it compiles just fine. Adding new objects is a little bit ornate but I can live with that. Anyways, Thanks a lot!

Comment: This should be the selected answer imo. This worked perfectly for me. Since g++ will be doing the linking with this technique, your assembly source files should have a global "main" symbol which is equivalent to C/C++'s main(). You also need to be careful about compiling a 32-bit target on a 64-bit host of course, but you can hack that with QMAKE_LFLAGS+=-m32.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to compile 64 bit MSVC 2017 with asm files using the following for my pro file.
Note: I was building a static library using MDd & MD cxx flags so that I could static link my library to another project but the ASM section at the bottom of the pro file should still work.

```
TEMPLATE = lib
TARGET = mystaticlib
INCLUDEPATH += .
CONFIG -= qt
CONFIG += staticlib
CONFIG -= debug_and_release debug_and_release_target
LIBS += -lws2_32

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_DEBUG += /MDd
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += /MD

win32: DESTDIR = ./

OBJECTS_DIR = ./.obj

HEADERS += myheader.h

SOURCES += mysource.cpp

#add additional compiler for asm source using MS 2017 macro assembler 64 bit
ml64.name = ML64 ${QMAKE_FILE_IN}
ml64.input = ASM_FILES
ml64.variable_out = OBJECTS
ml64.commands = ML64 /c ${QMAKE_FILE_NAME} /Fo ${QMAKE_FILE_OUT}
ml64.output = ${QMAKE_VAR_OBJECTS_DIR}${QMAKE_FILE_IN_BASE}$${first(QMAKE_EXT_OBJ)}
ml64.CONFIG += target_predeps

QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS  += ml64

ASM_FILES += \
      myx64.asm
```